# Domino Server Authentication Error - Weird

Tags: lotus-domino

We are receiving the following error message when people attempt to log in.

```
nHTTP: TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFASgKAAAADw== [173.164.83.101] authentication failure using internet password
```

Any ideas why this is happening and why it's preventing appropriate logins ?

Comment: Turns out it was a single sign-on setting problem. We fixed the setting and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a single sign-on setting problem. We fixed the setting and all is working.